# Visual Studio 2017 Extension Installition Error

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Hi I got installiton error in visual studio 2017 pro .But same extension works different machine ?Is anyone know this issue.By the way when I clear extension cache and retry that time it works

```
24/04/2018 09:08:51 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
24/04/2018 09:08:51 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
24/04/2018 09:08:51 - Found installed product - Global Location
24/04/2018 09:08:51 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Professional 2017
24/04/2018 09:09:00 - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at VSIXInstaller.LocationBasedSKU.get_RegRootHiveOverride()
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedVSSKU.InitializeSettingsManager()
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedVSSKU.get_Host()
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedVSSKU.CreateExtensionEngine()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionEngineForApplicableSKU(SupportedVSSKU supportedSKU, IInstallableExtension installableExtension, List`1 applicableSKUs, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.TryAddSkuToValidSkuList(SupportedVSSKU supportedSKU, IInstallableExtension extension, List`1 validSKUs, Boolean isRepairSupported)
24/04/2018 09:09:00 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, Boolean isRepairSupported, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Is it the custom extension or one in VS marketplace? If it works well after you clean up the cache, one possible reason is that it was related to the registry: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c483d83f-d640-4fe9-8ff7-af78d635df23/visual-studio-extension-caching-preventing-extensions-from-loading?forum=vsx

Comment: Hi Jack,custom extension,yesterday I find a solution,I use version selector to execute vsix with vs2017 and then it works.There are multiple visualstudio in machine may be some reason it looks version mismatch when I execute vsix directly...

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, you could share your solution as an answer(not a comment), so you could mark it as the answer, and it could help other community members who get the same issue find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)